# ConfigurationProperty is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, configurationmanager, configurationsection

I wanna **read/write (and save)** application's configuration file in program

The app.config is like this:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="AdWordsApi" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <AdWordsApi>
    <add key="LogPath" value=".\Logs\"/>
    ...
  </AdWordsApi>
</configuration>
```

When I use **ConfigurationManager.GetSection** to read the app.config, it works:

```
var adwords_section = (System.Collections.Hashtable) System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("AdWordsApi");
Console.WriteLine((string)adwords_section["LogPath"]);
```

But when I use **ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration**:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection("AdWordsApi");
Console.WriteLine(section["LogPath"]);
```

I always get this error:

> 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.this[System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty]'
>   is inaccessible due to its protection level

But as I know, **GetSection** cannot save configuration at program runtime, Like I said at beginning: I wanna save configuration at program runtime, So I have to use **OpenExeConfiguration**.

I have googled for long time, what I found is to use AppSettings, but what I use is custom section..

Anyone could explain why this "ConfigurationProperty is inaccessible" error occured? Thanks

**Edit:**

I have set **copy local** of *System* and *System.Configuration* to **true**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/12/custom-configuration-sections-in-3-easy-steps.aspx).

Edit:

you can use config:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="AdWordsApi.appSettings" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection" />
  </configSections>
  <AdWordsApi.appSettings>
    <add key="LogPath" value=".\Logs\"/>
  </AdWordsApi.appSettings>
```

this code:

```
    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
    var settings = config.GetSection("AdWordsApi.appSettings") as AppSettingsSection;
    if (settings != null) Console.Write(settings.Settings["LogPath"].Value);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Also You can use [this article](http://cstruter.com/blog/312).

Comment: I defined the AdwordsSettings as a subclass of ConfigurationSection as you said:http://pastecode.com/jF, and program stops here: string path = AdwordsSettings.Settings.LogPath with an NullReferenceException(Object not set to an instance of an object)

Comment: And when program stops there, I found AdwordsSettings.Settings is **null** in debugger

Comment: @gbstack, you should read that article in more details, or go through more similar articles to get better understanding of the configuration system, http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx. Your original error is expected, as you misunderstand how to read the section.

Comment: @LexLi, Thanks, I'll read it. Exactly I know little about Configuration system

Answer (score 23):

```
string key_value = refconfig.AppSettings.Settings["key_name"].Value;
```

Comment: that's what fixed my code anyway... derived from this "Configuration.AppSettings returns an AppSettingSections object,  AppSettingSections is derived from ConfigurationSection which is derived from ConfigurationElement which defines a this[] operator as "protected internal", which mean that it is "inaccessible due to its protection level."

 

You might want to try   cs.AppSettings.Settings["CompanyName"]);"

Comment: nice - worked for me, and saved me having to refactor my config settings. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it will work for what you are trying to do, but have you tried using ConfigurationUserLevel.None instead?

Comment: Thanks, but after using ConfigurationUserLevel.None and ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoaming, I still get the same error..