# How to make connection strings available in a T4 template?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t4

I've written a T4 template where I instantiate an EF context to read some data.
The problem is that the context cannot see the connection string from the Web.config.

How can I make the connection strings from the Web.config available to the template?

More info:

- template is written from scratch
- EF edmx is located in another project
- the first query I make in the template tells me that it cannot find the required connection string in the project where the template resides

---

Tried some of the solutions (thank you) below but I get this:

```
Error 2 Compiling transformation: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating12165CB53B43A726CBA54A29800255D257AAFD4D5F0DACE4DFE5872F2DEC7739EDF358F49C0444A912B851939903A79BC6180FCEB3FD0D1BF8C0093741DDDACA.GeneratedTextTransformation' does not contain a definition for 'Host' and no extension method 'Host' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating12165CB53B43A726CBA54A29800255D257AAFD4D5F0DACE4DFE5872F2DEC7739EDF358F49C0444A912B851939903A79BC6180FCEB3FD0D1BF8C0093741DDDACA.GeneratedTextTransformation' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have the following declared:

```
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating" #>
```

If I include the assembly for Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating it tells me that it's already inserted.

Also, is there any way to make the ConfigurationManager available to the DbContext so he can read w/e he wants behind the scenes without me passing him the connection string?

---

Solved it, thanks again:

```
<#@ template hostspecific="true" language="C#" debug="false" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Configuration" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Configuration" #>

var map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
map.ExeConfigFilename = this.Host.ResolvePath(@"..\Web.config");

var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var connectionString = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionName"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I accessed a connection string from App.config from T4 template in the following way:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>

ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap(this.Host.ResolvePath(@"..\ProjName\App.config"));
configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = this.Host.ResolvePath(@"..\ProjName\App.config");
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
string connectionString = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: "hostspecific" option is necessary in order to use this.Host:

Comment: I do not have any App.Config available, so this is not much helpful

Comment: I get the following: when I try this: `Compiling transformation: 'ConfigurationElement.this[ConfigurationProperty]' is inaccessible due to its protection` and can not find a good solution anywhere online.

Comment: this failed for me until I called the empty constructor for `ExeConfigurationFileMap` as in `var configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();`

Comment: @mattnificent fixed case with `AppSettings` by https://stackoverflow.com/a/29424434/2346621 `refconfig.AppSettings.Settings["key_name"].Value`. Try the same thing with `ConnectionStrings`. Also maybe try `ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoaming`

Answer (score 5):

[Injecting Your Web.Config Connection String Into Your T4 Template](http://overwhelmed-with-code.blogspot.com/2011/11/injecting-your-webconfig-connection.html) provides you a T4 template that reads connection string from web.config and app.config. I created my custom version based on it and that saved me a good bit of time.

> ```
> <#@ assembly name="System.Configuration" #>
> <#@ assembly name="EnvDTE" #>
> <#@ assembly name="System.Core.dll" #>
> <#@ import namespace="System" #>
> <#@ import namespace="System.Configuration" #>
> <#@ import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" #>
> <#+
>
> /// <summary>
> /// Provides strongly typed access to the hosting EnvDTE.Project and app.config/web.config
> /// configuration file, if present.
> ///
> /// Typical usage from T4 template:
> /// <code>ConfigurationAccessor config = new ConfigurationAccessor((IServiceProvider)this.Host);</code>
> ///
> /// </summary>
> /// <author>Sky Sanders [sky.sanders@gmail.com, http://skysanders.net/subtext]</author>
> /// <date>01-23-10</date>
> /// <copyright>The contents of this file are a Public Domain Dedication.</copyright>
> ///
> /// TODO: determine behaviour of ProjectItem.FileNames when referred to a linked file.
> ///
> public class ConfigurationAccessor
> {
>
>  /// <summary>
>  /// Typical usage from T4 template:
>  /// <code>ConfigurationAccessor config = new ConfigurationAccessor((IServiceProvider)this.Host);</code>
>  /// </summary>
>  public ConfigurationAccessor(IServiceProvider host) : this(host, null)
>  {  }
>
>  /// <summary>
>  /// Same as default constructor but it looks for a web.config/app.config in the passed config
>  /// project location and not in the first startup project it finds. The configProjectLocation
>  /// passed should be relative to the solution file.
>  /// </summary>
>  public ConfigurationAccessor(IServiceProvider host, string configProjectLocation)
>  {
>   // Get the instance of Visual Studio that is hosting the calling file
>   EnvDTE.DTE env = (EnvDTE.DTE)host.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));
>
>   // Initialize configuration filename
>   string configurationFilename=null;
>
>   // Gets an array of currently selected projects. Since you are either in this file saving it or
>   // right-clicking the item in solution explorer to invoke the context menu it stands to reason
>   // that there is 1 ActiveSolutionProject and that it is the parent of this file....
>   _project = (EnvDTE.Project)((Array)env.ActiveSolutionProjects).GetValue(0);
>
>   // Try and find the configuration file in the active solution project
>   configurationFilename = FindConfigurationFilename(_project);
>
>   // If we didn't find the configuration file, check the startup project or passed config
>   // project location in the constructor
>   if (configurationFilename == null)
>   {
>    // We are going to get the first *STARTUP* project in the solution
>    // Our startup projects should also have a valid web.config/app.config, however,
>    // if for some reason we have more than one startup project in the solution, this
>    // will just grab the first one it finds
>    //
>    // We can also supply a config project location to look for in the constructor. This solves
>    // the problem in the case where we have multiple startup projects and this file is not
>    // in the first, or the config file is not in either the startup project or the active solution
>    // project.
>    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(configProjectLocation))
>    {
>     _project = (EnvDTE.Project)env.Solution.Projects.Item(configProjectLocation);
>    }
>    else
>    {
>     foreach (String s in (Array)env.Solution.SolutionBuild.StartupProjects)
>     {
>      _project = (EnvDTE.Project)env.Solution.Projects.Item(s);
>      break;
>     }
>    }
>
>    // Try and find the configuration file in one of the projects we found
>    configurationFilename = FindConfigurationFilename(_project);
>   }
>
>   // Return the configuration object if we have a configuration file name
>   // If we do not have a configuration file name, throw an exception
>   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(configurationFilename))
>   {
>    // found it, map it and expose salient members as properties
>    ExeConfigurationFileMap configFile = null;
>    configFile = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
>    configFile.ExeConfigFilename=configurationFilename;
>    _configuration = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFile, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
>    }
>   else
>   {
>    throw new ArgumentException("Unable to find a configuration file (web.config/app.config). If the config file is located in a different project, you must mark that project as either the Startup Project or pass the project location of the config file relative to the solution file.");
>   }
>  }
>
>  /// <summary>
>  /// Finds a web.config/app.config file in the passed project and returns the file name.
>  /// If none are found, returns null.
>  /// </summary>
>  private string FindConfigurationFilename(EnvDTE.Project project)
>  {
>   // examine each project item's filename looking for app.config or web.config
>   foreach (EnvDTE.ProjectItem item in project.ProjectItems)
>   {
>    if (Regex.IsMatch(item.Name,"(app|web).config",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
>    {
>     // TODO: try this with linked files. is the filename pointing to the source?
>     return item.get_FileNames(0);
>    }
>   }
>
>   // not found, return null
>   return null;
>  }
>
>  private EnvDTE.Project _project;
>  private System.Configuration.Configuration _configuration;
>
>  /// <summary>
>  /// Provides access to the host project.
>  /// </summary>
>  /// <remarks>see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.aspx</remarks>
>  public EnvDTE.Project Project
>  {
>   get { return _project; }
>  }
>
>  /// <summary>
>  /// Convenience getter for Project.Properties.
>  /// Examples:
>  /// <code>string thisAssemblyName = config.Properties.Item("AssemblyName").Value.ToString();</code>
>  /// <code>string thisAssemblyName = config.Properties.Item("AssemblyName").Value.ToString();</code>
>  /// </summary>
>  /// <remarks>see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project_properties.aspx</remarks>
>  public EnvDTE.Properties Properties
>  {
>   get { return _project.Properties;}
>  }
>
>  /// <summary>
>  /// Provides access to the application/web configuration file.
>  /// </summary>
>  /// <remarks>see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.aspx</remarks>
>  public System.Configuration.Configuration Configuration
>  {
>   get { return _configuration; }
>  }
>
>  /// <summary>
>  /// Provides access to the appSettings section of the configuration file.
>  /// Behavior differs from typical AppSettings usage in that the indexed
>  /// item's .Value must be explicitly addressed.
>  /// <code>string setting = config.AppSettings["MyAppSetting"].Value;</code>
>  /// </summary>
>  /// <remarks>see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.appsettings.aspx</remarks>
>  public  KeyValueConfigurationCollection AppSettings
>  {
>   get { return _configuration.AppSettings.Settings;}
>  }
>
>  /// <summary>
>  /// Provides access to the connectionStrings section of the configuration file.
>  /// Behavior is as expected; items are accessed by string key or integer index.
>  /// <code>string northwindProvider = config.ConnectionStrings["northwind"].ProviderName;</code>
>  /// </summary>
>  /// <remarks>see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.connectionstrings.aspx</remarks>
>  public  ConnectionStringSettingsCollection ConnectionStrings
>  {
>   get { return _configuration.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings;}
>  }
> }
> #>
> ```

Comment: This solution has problems when projects are nested within Solution Folders. I was able to work around the problem with code from here: http://www.wwwlicious.com/2011/03/29/envdte-getting-all-projects-html/

Answer (score 1):

If anyone needs to resolve absolute path to a Web.config file (because e.g. a .tt file is included and used from multiple other .tt files in different relative paths):

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Configuration" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Configuration" #>
<#+
string GetConnectionString()
{
    var map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
    var configPath = Path.Combine(
        Host.ResolveAssemblyReference("$(SolutionDir)"), "WwwFolderInSolution", "Web.config");

    map.ExeConfigFilename = configPath;

    var config = ConfigurationManager.
        OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    return config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
}
#>
```