# Accessing Values from configSections of App.Config of different application

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I am trying to read values from the different `configSections` of `App.Config` file from a different application using this code:

```
public string ReadValue(string FileName,string Key)
        {
     //File name is the path of the App.Config from a different application
         ExeConfigurationFileMap configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
         configMap.ExeConfigFilename = FileName;

         Configuration config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

         var section =config.GetSection("dev") as AppSettingsSection ;
            return section[Key];


         }
```

I am getting error as `System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.this[System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty]' is inaccessible due to its protection level`

How do I get this code working?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587614/configurationproperty-is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level)

Comment: i dont think its the same thing, because this code tries to access the app.config file from a file path and therefore cannot use OpenExeConfiguration

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Double click on your Settings.settings file.
- Change your Access Modifier to: Public

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: well, there is no property for Access Modifier for Config File in Console Application

Comment: Yes there is. See the screenshot I added to my answer and the red rectangle.